# How do I get Microsoft Edge (Chromium based) to open M3U by shell instead of downloading the file?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium

When I click an `m3u` file hyperlink on a web page, Microsoft Edge shows a "Save As ..." file dialog. But I want it to open a media player (e.g. WinAmp) with that `m3u` file.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose **Always open files of this type** when you click and download a `m3u` file at the first time in Edge Chromium:

[image]

After that, when you click `m3u` links again in Edge Chromium, it will open it directly in the default media player you set (but it will still download the file):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very comprehensive solution! (I expected Edge to offer a handler choice first before defaulting to download, like Firefox does.) — Can I keep Edge from downloading the file to the `Downloads` folder? I don't need it after the shell has been launched.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't prevent Edge from downloading the file. It's not like in Edge Legacy we can choose save or open. If you need this feature in Edge, I suggest that you can provide a feedback through Edge **Send feedback** button and the developing team will look into the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, again, for sharing your knowledge. So, I just posted a feedback comment.